# Sending MIDI from Ableton to a rack mount delay through a sound module

Tags: midi

Okay, I have a Scarlett 18i8 connected to my MacBook.  I also have a piano connected via USB to the MacBook.

One of the musicians has a 19" rack mount delay unit with MIDI in/out, traditional 5-pin.  Occasionally he plays with a delay that's horribly out of sync with the rest of the band.

If I enable SYNC in Ableton's preferences for the Scarlett 18i8's MIDI port, will a clock signal be sent out of the 5-pin connection on the Scarlett to the delay hardware?  Is it that simple?  Do I need SYNC *and* REMOTE or just SYNC?

I'm trying to avoid adding a USB to MIDI adapter to the macbook, and if the Scarlett 18i8 can double as that, then I think I've solved the issue.  Am I on the right track?

Comment: What is the brand and type of the rack delay?

Comment: Can't remember, but I do know that CC 23 controls delay timing on that unit.

Comment: This question isn't about sound design as per our site scope, but is about MIDI implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of rack delay. Some devices accept an incoming clock signal. This way you can just enable SYNC in Ableton and connect the two devices with a MIDI cable.

If the device doesn't know how to handle MIDI clock, you need the Remote setting and set the value manually. This means figuring out what the MIDI value is to be in time with the song and send that value on the start of a song. You can use MIDI clips for this with CC-OUT.